# Based on condition how to pass coming props's data or props's default in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

in template

```
       <div :style="{width:screenCheckFunc(width) }></div>
```

props

```
data: {
  screenWidth: window.innerWidth,
},

props: {
 width: {
   type: String,
   default: "35.5rem"
 },
 padding: {
   type: String,
   default: "2rem"
}
```

in methods

```
screenCheckFunc(val){
  if(this.screenWidth > 1024){
       return val
      } else {
        val.default <-- something like this
      }
    }
```

(in `val` i want pass props)

Is it possible to pass props's default in `else` using func?

edit

sorry for if question was unclear.

```
<div :style="{width:screenWidth > 1024 ? width : '35.rem' ,padding:screenWidth > 1024 ? padding : '2rem'  }></div>
```

like this if i write ternary i needed to write `screenWidth > 1024` over and over again can simplify this ternary to a function so i just call function and pass down props?

Comment: there are 2 defaults mentioning your code. One is in your props and the other is in your method. Which one you need to use?

Comment: @tuhin47 last one is an example(```val.default```). I want use (width's default.  in example) or any other default that declared in props.

Comment: `<div :style="{width:screenCheckFunc(width = 35.5) ></div>` how about this?

Comment: you can remove else. `val` by default is already `35.5rem`

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw When if i remove else it will become none because i written in `style` it will disappear and will not get default value.

Comment: I see, i think you just need to add another data for default width. That way, you can `this.screenWidth > 1024 ? val : this.defaults.width`

Comment: you can declare your `defaults` variable outside export default so you can use it in the props and data

Answer (score 1):

You can access the default value using
`this.$options.props['propName'].default`.
In your case you can access the default value of the prop `width` by `this.$options.props['width'].default`

You can use these:

```
<div :style="screenCheckScreenWidthAndSetStyle()"></div>
```

and

```
screenCheckScreenWidthAndSetStyle() {
   if (this.screenWidth > 1024) {
      return {width: this.width, padding: this.padding};
   } else {
      return {width: this.$options.props['width'].default, padding: this.$options.props['padding'].default};
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an array of objects like this and pass it as props:

```
widthSizes:[
  {size:'1024' , width:'35.5'},
  {size:'320' , width:'20'}]


screenCheckFunc(val){
(let width in this.widthSizes){
    if(width.size === val){
        return val.width
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah if it was only with but i want pass many kind props that used in style e.g padding, height etc... which is all defaults are different but all of them needed check screen size. Of course i can check in style e.g .. ``` :style="{width:screenWidth > 1024 ? width : '35.5rem', padding: screenWidth > 1024 ? width : '2rem'}``` and so on . Because it's component sometimes needed different style than in css, so cant write in css with media too.

Comment: I edited my answer and I hope that it can help you.